# Is there a connections limit on bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, connection

I don't know if it is a lot or a few, but I see this number of connections:

```
bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo | grep connections
```

> "connections": 66,

It does not seem to get over 70, is there an in-built limit? If yes, can I tweak the limit of connections to get higher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, bitcoin-core allows up to 125 connections to different peers, 8 of which are outbound. You can therefore, have at most 117 inbound connections.

I think there is no need to handhold bitcoind to control the connection management.

You could try to limit the maximum connections with `-maxconnections=<num>` to reduce the amount of internet traffic produce by your node.